# json formatting in C#

Tags: c#, json, formatting

I am tring a xml data convert to json. 
but I got a issue.

```
        string xml = "<Test><Name>Test class</Name><X>100</X><Y>200</Y></Test>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        return    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

when display datavisualizer

```
{"Test":{"Name":"Test class","X":"100","Y":"200"}}
```

but page return it

```
"{\"Test\":{\"Name\":\"Test class\",\"X\":\"100\",\"Y\":\"200\"}}"
```

it not a valid json.

how to format it?

Comment: are you using ajax to get this data...

Comment: Also, is this string as you receive it (and save it) from a client app, or in the debugger?  That escaping of the quotes looks like a debugger artifact...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually happening is you already passing json string to the client, so at client if you give dataType as "json" it will again serialize string and will get above result.

fact is this is not invalid json actually, you need it to parse to get json object

at client side...using javascript

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse("{\"Test\":{\"Name\":\"Test class\",\"X\":\"100\",\"Y\":\"200\"}}");
```

Comment: Thank you bro..
I am new in JQuery+JSON.
my mistake.